Norm on the space of rapidly decreasing and continuous functions
In P.Malliavin’s book "Integration and probability" a continuous function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be of rapidly decrease if for all integer $m$ we have that the mapping $(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^m f(x)$ goes to $0$ as $\lVert x\rVert$ goes to infinity. Then, a norm on this space is defined by  $\lVert f\rVert_{m,0}=\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}(1+\lVert x\rVert^2)^m\lvert f(x)\rvert$.
I do not understand the use of the maximum instead of the supremum. I think we may be able to prove that the above mapping is bounded and use the supremum. However I cannot see why this supremum should be reached.
If you have any idea on what’s going on here or some hints to provide, I will be happy to read it !
Thank you

If $f=0$ then the supremum is zero, which is achieved by all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so the supremum is also a maximum.
Else, there must be a $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for which $(1+||y||^2)|f(y)|>0$.  Define
$$v=(1+||y||^2)|f(y)|$$
Since $v>0$, by the "rapid-decreasing" assumption on $f$, there is a radius $r>0$ for which $$(1+||x||^2)^m|f(x)|< v \quad \mbox{whenever $||x||>r$}$$
So we can search for the supremum over the compact set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n:||x||\leq r\}$. Since $f$ is assumed to be continuous, the continuous function $(1+||x||^2)^m|f(x)|$ has a well defined maximum over this compact set, so, the supremum is achieved and can be called a maximum.

Thank you a lot !
